# MongoDb: How to merge contents of two documents in mongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I allow user to skip login or login using FB. When user logs in I create user in User collection using FB profile ID and when he skips it I still create his user using some unique client ID. In the client app, user can bookmark articles and I sync it to server. User can login using FB at any time later. Once user logs in using FB  I have to merge user created using FB and user created using Client ID so that his stored data maps perfectly.

**What I have tried:**

Consider user skipped login and I create a user in USER collection.
User logs in using FB in between life time of the app and I will search this FB ID in my collection. If this ID does not exist I update skipped user document with FB id. If it exist I will merge data from FB user document to skipped user document and delete FB user document.

Another method:

I don't sync any bookmark to the server until user logs in. Once he logs in I will sync all data at once.

What is the efficient way of doing this kind of operation?

Comment: Do you have two separate Collections for FB user and logged in user?

Comment: No. It is same collection..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11056632/2-documents-merge-in-mongodb

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need to find the document with the same `clientId`, and add to it the facebook user document.

You can do this with mongo update command, using `$set` which merges the new document with the existing mongo document https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/

so your code would look like this

```
db.collection("users").update(
   // first parameter is mongo query to match based on clientId
   { clientId: 100 },
   // second parameter is the document that will be merged using $set
   { $set: facebookDocument })
```

The result of this will be the existing document merged with all the properties of `facebookDocument`

Comment: $set never merges two document

Comment: It adds the properties from the passed document to the existing document, is this not the merge you mean?